# How do I enter a required field in the text area?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to leave the **comment** field as required in my PHP application, however due to not having proper knowledge I have not found the solution so far. This is my "echo" where PHP generates the comment field. I will not post all the code in my application, as it is very long, but the main one is just below.

```html
 echo "<textarea cols='45' rows='7' name='comment' >".$this->fields["comment"]."</textarea>";
```

Text field

[image]

Comment: its a bad idea to echo javascript like that. close php, write your script and then reopen php as needed. anyway, you need to quote your string.. `value:'".$this->fields["satisfaction"]."'`

Comment: Pamblam!       I did not understand very well, as would the javascript out PHP. Could you give me an example? What I want to do is, if it is equal or less than 3 review should be mandatory on the form, but do not know if the to implement the code.

Comment: if your question is about javascript, remove the php and show us the generated javascript.

Comment: Pamblam!  I added more information to better understanding. Any doubt I am available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution to make this field as required is to add attribute "[required](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)", therefore:

```
echo "<textarea cols='45' rows='7' name='comment' required>".$this->fields["comment"]."</textarea>";
```

And the browser will inform user to fill in this `<textarea>` field.

Answer (score 2):

The form is an HTML form, you are generating HTML using php that's all. Its not a PHP form. You're already using the jquery ok library, so I would suggest at looking at using the jquery validate plugin to add form validation to your form.

Comment: Ben Cummins! How do I validate the form using jQuery plugins? I lay in Jquery.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who took the time to help. I will test here.